# Live wallpaper openGL using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, live-wallpaper

I have created android live wallpaper using openGL.It works fine.Now I want to set the settings in my live wallpaper using shared preferences.I don't know how to get the preferences value.

Can anyone tell me how could I get shared preferences value and use it for rendering sphere.This is my preferences xml,

```
    <PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<ListPreference
    android:entryValues="@array/textureitems_values"
    android:entries="@array/textureitems"
    android:summary="Select rotation speed"
    android:title="Rotation Speed"
    android:key="rotspeed"
    >
</ListPreference>
<ListPreference
    android:entryValues="@array/planetitems_values"
    android:entries="@array/planetitems"
    android:summary="Select Planet"
    android:title="Planet"
    android:key="moreapps"
    >
</ListPreference>
<ListPreference
    android:entryValues="@array/timeitems_values"
    android:entries="@array/timeitems"
    android:summary="Select time"
    android:title="Time"
    android:key="time"
    >
</ListPreference>

<Preference android:title="More Apps" android:summary="To want more apps like this" android:key="mypref" />
```

From which class I can get the preference value and apply those values to render?

**EDIT:** This is the code I am trying,This is in wallpaper Service,

```
      class MyEngine extends GLEngine implements
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener,
        SensorEventListener {
    NeheLesson08Renderer renderer;

    public MyEngine() {
        super();
        // handle prefs, other initialization
        renderer = new NeheLesson08Renderer();
        sharedPreferences = NeheLesson08WallpaperService.this.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, 0);
        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences, null);
        renderer.setContext(getBaseContext());
        setRenderer(renderer);
        setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }
           public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
         sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String rotspeed = null;
         String storedPreference = sharedPreferences.getString("rotspeed", "key");
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
         editor.putString("rotspeed", storedPreference); // value to store
         editor.commit();
         System.out.println("stored procedure values::"+storedPreference);
    }
```

This is in Renderer class

```
            storedPreference= sharedPreferences.getString("rotspeed", "key");
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

     editor.putString("rotspeed", storedPreference); // value to store
     editor.commit();
     System.out.println("stored procedure values in rendere::"+storedPreference);
```

My Logcat looks like,

```
                 06-26 01:42:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4778): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
           06-26 01:42:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4778): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
           06-26 01:42:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4778):  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:224)
           06-26 01:42:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4778):  at com.srashtaa.planets3dgalaxylivewallpaper.NeheLesson08Renderer.LoadPreferences(NeheLesson08Renderer.java:155)
           06-26 01:42:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4778):  at com.srashtaa.planets3dgalaxylivewallpaper.NeheLesson08Renderer.setContext(NeheLesson08Renderer.java:146)
           06-26 01:42:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4778):  at com.srashtaa.planets3dgalaxylivewallpaper.NeheLesson08WallpaperService$MyEngine.<init>(NeheLesson08WallpaperService.java:42)
           06-26 01:42:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(4778):  at com.srashtaa.planets3dgalaxylivewallpaper.NeheLesson08WallpaperService.onCreateEngine(NeheLesson08WallpaperService.java:26)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Post contents of logs too

Comment: I pasted my logcat details

Comment: What is `storedPreference`?

Comment: It is a string variable

Comment: I mean in the Renderer class

Comment: Yes it is a string variable

Answer (score 0):

Write a `PreferenceActivity` class which uses xml in the question. Use `SharedPreferences` in the `onCreate`:

```
public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.<YourXml>);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        //Get preference values
        String value = prefs.getString(<Key>, <DefaultValue>);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I place the code you mentioned in my settings activity.How Can I access or get preference values?

Comment: I have tried your code It obtain the shared preference value but I unable to use this value.Where I got classcastexception.Shall I paste my code